# MariaDB randomly sets timestamp to null

Tags: jdbc, timestamp, mariadb

Production CentOS 6.5 server told me to upgrade to `MariaDB` from `MySQL`.  I now realise that there may not be a version of `MariaDB` ready for commercial use.

Now I have a problem where timestamp fields randomly changes to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (or null??).  It might happen on one of every 100 records.  I only ever create a timestamp using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` at record creation.

In `MySQL` `JDBC` connector I had set the `zeroDateTimeBehaviour=null` for some reason.  This setting is not available in `MariaDB` `JDBC` connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using different connector then you need to use the mariadb driver for sure (also change JDBC connection string)

check https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-the-mariadb-java-client/

*Please note that the driver class provided by the MariaDB Client Library for Java Applications is not **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** but **org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver**!*

updating timestamp will not work otherwise and when update or insert fails you get the 0000-00-00 00:00:00

I had this same problem when switching from MySQL to MariaDB...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on values, here you can find some probable reasons:
 [mariadb - timestamp](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/)